# Windows processes and services

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, services

What does the "-k" mean in the executabl path: C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs for LanmanServer? I've looked in various books and searched online extensively and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a parameter subkey that points to a dll file of the service using the process. 
Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost.exe